# Is there an advantage to struct sizes that are powers of 2?

Tags: anchor

Some of the larger defi projects using Anchor add padding to the end of every struct to reach the nearest power of 2. Is there a performance or practical advantage to doing so?

For example:

```
// Size = 1 + 8 + 32 + 32 * 20 + 343 = 1024
#[account(zero_copy)]
pub struct SomeStruct {
    pub version: u8,
    pub last_updated: i64,
    pub authority: Pubkey,
    pub addresses: [Pubkey; 20],
    pub reserved: [u8; 343],
}
```

Comment: The main advantage of power of two structs is processor speed. These micro-optimizations seem pretty far down from the top of the list of Solana performance bottlenecks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from reserving space, padding is also could be done to accomodate the zerocopy feature a key requirement of zerocopy is that your struct is perfectly aligned/ has no automatically added padding by the compiler,
to be zero copy compatible your type must follow the rules to be P.O.D(plain old data type)
refrence : https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/trait.Pod.html

Answer (score 2):

There is a practical advantage to padding since it gives you room to expand the data structure in future without having to resize every account. I don't know about the powers of two thing. Good question.